# how parse console on travis-ci and find the number of occured word

Tags: shell, maven, xpath, console, travis-ci

I use github + travis-ci for continuous integration. I have a maven project with lot of tests. I want parse all console and find a special word by xpath. If this word is present x times my job is OK else my job is KO.

how parse console on travis-ci and find the number of occured word by xpath or other method?

Comment: Please show examples of the typical input, and desired output.

Comment: example: https://travis-ci.org/sgrillon14/flags-rest-service can be contain <EXPECTED_RESULTS>Tests run: 4066, Failures: 162, Errors: 0, Skipped: 785<\/EXPECTED_RESULTS> and I want chek if "Tests run: 4066, Failures: 162, Errors: 0, Skipped: 785" occured n time (n=5 for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with travis API =>

```
travis logs
```

But with this API is not possible because I have a infinite loop (this command copy logs to logs so copy logs to logs so copy copy ...). This API is good if you read the logs of others builds only!!!

---

And I find a solution:

**in .travis.yml file:**

```
script:
- test/run.sh
```

**in run.sh file:**

```
curl -s "https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/${TRAVIS_JOB_ID}/log.txt?deansi=true" > nonaui.log

expectation=`sed -n 's:.*<EXPECTED_RESULTS>\(.*\)</EXPECTED_RESULTS>.*:\1:p' nonaui.log | head -n 1`
nb_expectation=`sed -n ":;s/$expectation//p;t" nonaui.log | sed -n '$='`

# 3 = 1 (real) + 2 counters (Excel and CSV)
if [ "$nb_expectation" == "3" ]; then
    echo "******** All counter is SUCCESS"
else
    echo "******** All counter is FAIL"
    exit 255
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given [log.txt](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/214040832/log.txt) as input, and desired input lines like these:

```
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.957 sec - in TestSuite
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Assuming we just want to test the "*10*", this might do:

```
n=5
awk -F '[ ,]*' '/^Tests run:/ \
               { if ($3>'$n') { print "OK found " $3 ; x=$3 ; exit} } \
               END {if (x<'$n') print "Fail."} ' log.txt
```

Output:

```
OK found 10
```

Comment: My question is on travis-ci (on cloud), not on a personal server.

Comment: This Q is tagged "*shell*" -- please clarify just what sort of shell is being referred to.

Comment: Travis exe a shell (script: - test/run.sh) in .travis.yml